# for loop inside if condition in php

Tags: php, for-loop, if-statement

I need to run set of code inside `for-loop`  only if certain condition is satisfied like:

```
@for($i = 0; $i <= $date_diffrence; $i++)
   @if(condition)
      $temp = $i; 
      @for($multDayCount=0; $multDayCount<count($dayDifferenceArr); $multDayCount++)
         $i = $dayDifferenceArr[$multDayCount];

   @endif

<code_section>  

   @if(condition)
      @endfor
       $i = $temp;
   @endif
 @endfor
```

I want the  to run regardless of the if- for condition. How can I loop like this? Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: are you asking a question or answering yourself ?

Comment: I dont think you could end the inner for-loop before ending the second if-statement.

Comment: What exactly are you trying to achieve here?

Answer (score 0):

Your question as stated is self–answering — if you need to have `if` inside of a loop you just... can. :)

Looking at your code (which is not quite PHP looking?..) you also seem to want to *terminate* the loop conditionally?

In PHP loops can be controlled with [`break`](http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.break.php) and [`continue`](http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.continue.php). You example looks like it's trying to `break` the loop conditionally.

Comment: I need for loop inside if. The above code is just a structure which i need and not the exact php code. I need the <code_section> to be executed regardless of the 'if' condition.

Comment: @tyro I would recommend trying to write actual PHP code for an example. It's not clear what you mean by "regardless". Anything outside of a condition executes regardless of it.